# javascript function executed without calling the function

Tags: javascript, function

I have below simple javascript:

```js
function write(msg)
    {
      document.getElementById("para").innerHTML+=msg;
    }

    var baz= new function
    {
      write("abc");    
    }
```

And without calling baz, the inner text of para is updated to be "abc".
Why it is being called?

thanks

Comment: thats not even a valid code snippet. kindly check

Comment: That's looks like an illegal function definition. I don't know how that's possibly being parsed, but it must be running the body immediately. Put () after `function`.

Comment: Code above should have the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`, I assume you just have a typo in your example code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because of the `new`. It treats the function afterwards as a class constructor and calls it to construct a new instance. It might be a but easier to understand if you take:

```
 function Something() {
   alert("works");
 }

 const sth = new Something;
```

Now just move the function and you got:

```
 const sth = new function() {
  alert("works");
 };
```

which is exactly what happens in your case.